# Refresh data received from an API every minute React, Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am working on a little project that involves getting the weather at different locations and also, dynamically getting the time at those locations afterwards. All these worked fine but then i tried to take it a step further by attempting to refresh the data gotten from the API every minute(without resubmitting/pressing the enter key).
I've tried various ways of implementing the setinterval function into the code but none seem to work. Here is what the code looks like:

```
function App() {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
    const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});
    const [timeZone, setTimeZone] = useState({});

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setQuery(e.target.value);
    };
    const apiCall = () => {
        Axios({
            method: "get",
            url: `${api.timeBase}apiKey=${api.timeKey}&location=${query}`,
            timeout: 10000, 
        })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data);
                setWeather(res.data);
                //setQuery("");
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        apiCall();
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(apiCall, 60000);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (weather.main !== undefined) {
            Axios.get(
                `${api.timeBase}apiKey=${api.timeKey}&location=${weather.name}, ${weather.sys.country}`
            )
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res.data);
                    setTimeZone(res.data);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        }
    }, [weather]);
```

Basically, the issue i get the most is that somewhere within the setinterval function, the `query`parameter is cleared and the API continues to retrieve a different location till gets back to normal. i tried preventing the `query` parameter from clearing after it updates the state, that didnt help.

PS: i had to breakdown the `handlesubmit` because attaching the setinterval to the original block of code throws an error cause e.preventDefault isn't defined. Also, I think calling the setInterval without the useEffect makes things a lot worse too.

Comment: I think it should refresh data because useEffect is calling apiCall function every one minute accurately.There must be some other problem

Answer (score 2):

Clear out the interval after the interval is finished. The `setInterval` function returns a `timerId` that should be cleared out otherwise, it remains in the timer pool and can execute even after the instance of the callback has been run.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   const id = setInterval(apiCall, 60000);
   return () => clearInterval(id);
}, []);
```

Comment: i think i actually just solved it now. i passed in the `query` as a dependency to the useEffect that bears the setInterval. everything seems to be working as expected. whew!